# How to add 12V PSU and 12V battery together to power the PCB

Tags: power-supply, pcb, switching, battery-operated, powermosfet

[image]I have designed a PCB. Now I am facing a issue that I want to use 12V PSU and 12V battery together so that if 12V PSU fails then 12V battery can supply power to PCB.Battery charging is not part of the project as i will remove battery when it is discharged and will attach to PCB after it is fully charged. Current requirement of my PCB is 3A. Now the issue is

How can I setup both power sources in my schematic that if PSU turns off then battery can supply power to whole PCB, Keeping in mind that my current requirement is 3A?

Basically, I need some switching circuit but with high current requirement.

Comment: How fast does the changeover need to happen, and what is the minimum voltage it can work with while the changeover is happening?

Comment: I am operating a NIMA17 stepper motor and a 5V servo motor with the PCB using esp32-s3 module. Changeover should be fast enough maintain PCB operations without intereption.@AndrewMorton

Comment: You'll need to add a block diagram to the question so that we can see exactly where the power rails are going, including the charging for the battery.

Comment: You will probably want a charge controller chip with automatic power path control and battery charging functionality built in, since you probably won't want to be unplugging and topping up the backup battery every few weeks.  Specific recommendations are off-topic but this is an extremely common use case and there are products out there; I'm looking at one now.

Comment: I dont want battery charging circuit. When battery is drain then i will simply remove it and will attach again with pcb after it is fully charged. I want to add the circuit in my PCB. I am attaching block diagram of system so that you can better understand

Comment: We can maybe find any such module but i want to integrate this circuit in my PCB. That's why I need some reference circuitry.

Comment: @Robert Have you already tried anything, like a changeover relay with the coil energised by the PSU and a fair size holdup capacitor for the ESP32? (It might need a separate regulator from the 5 V servo motor.) The momentum of the motors could well keep them going in the short time it takes the relay to change over.

Comment: Note that lead acid battery charging is not very difficult. You might consider adding built-in charging even if you don't need it

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest solution is to use two diodes. However, in this case, it would be good for the PSU voltage to be slightly higher than the battery so that it has a higher priority for power delivery.
[image]

Comment: My  current requirement is 3A. Will i get any diode which has forward current ogf 3A?

Comment: I think that diodes with a current above 5A and a voltage above 30V would be the best. My favorite is a double diode from an old AT/ATX power supply, e.g. SBL2030CT, BYV118.

Comment: There is one more question in my mind. My NIMA 17 Stepper motor is operating at 12V. So these diodes will drop about 0.6V. So i will get approx. 11.3 to 11.4V. Will NIMA 17 stepper motor work with 11.3V instead of 12V?

Comment: The voltage drop of 0.6 V for 12 V (5%) is negligible in most applications, and certainly for the motor power supply.